# How to measure memory consumption in Cooja

Tags: contiki, cooja

I am trying to simulate a wireless sensor network using Cooja simulator. I want to observe the amount of memory the RPL protocol consumes in Contiki-OS. I used sky-mote for my simulation and I created a network with a number of them. Is there any way I can observe the amount of memory the RPL protocol consumes for keeping the neighbors and the routing tables?

Answer (score 1):

Run `msp430-size`.

```
$ msp430-size hello-world.sky 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  46373     254    7348   53975    d2d7 hello-world.sky
```

The sum of the `data` and `bss` values is the total static memory (RAM) size.

There is also the size used by the stack in the runtime (Contiki on the sky platform has no heap memory), but neighbors and routes are stored in the static memory allocated at the compilation time.

Comment: what is the file name for the implementation of RPL in ContikiOS?